# Dealing with combining cases & duplicate cases in switch statements

Tags: javascript, optimization, switch-statement, case-statement

Is it okay to combine `cases` that share assignments and repeat the `case` for assignments that are not shared, or is it preferred to just keep each separated?

---

*To illustrate with a simple example.. `case 0` and `180` both include `w = 330` so they have been combined; the value assigned to `x` is different for each so they are repeated to do the `x` assignment.*

```
switch(window.orientation) {
    case   0:
    case 180:
        w = 330;
        //break
    case   0:
        x = '-180px';
        //break
    case -90:
    case  90:
        w = 480;
        x = '0';
        break;
    case 180:
        x = '-80px';
        break;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't combine since case 0 and case 180 have different x values (might possibly if the branches were identical).  I would avoid combining cases due to difficult readability/later maintainability alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it comes to do more than one operation per element in a `switch` statement, it's always better to not repeat the same `case` twice. You can easily achieve this by summing up all the fragments of code that are under the same `case`.

For example, if you want to perform operation `A` on `case 0` and operation `B` on `case 0` and `case 1` then you should do something like this:

```
switch(variable) {
    case 0:
        // operation A;
    case 1:
        // operation B;
        break;
}
```

This will execute both operation `A` and `B` on `case 0`, because there's no `break` on `case 0`.

Now let's assume you write something like this:

```
switch(variable) {
    case 1:
        x = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        x = 2;
        break;
}
```

The above code will end up assigning the value `1` to the variable `x`. The second `case 1`, saying `x = 2` will never be reached, because of the `break` statement in the first `case 1`.

So if you have got to perform different operations on `case 0` and `case 1`, but they share some operation, that's better to separate the cases repeating some lines of code instead of writing `case 1` twice, because this makes your code easier to read and slightly faster.

So in your code, the best way to achieve what you want is this one:

```
switch(window.orientation) {
    case   0:
        x = '-180px';
        w = 330;
        break;
    case 180:
        x = '-80px';
        w = 330;
        break;
    case -90:
    case  90:
        w = 480;
        x = '0';
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say don't combine - too high of a chance of making a mistake...like you did.  The 2nd `case 180` will never be reached, since the first one has a `break;` after it.

If everything is the same, I think it's ok to combine though (like the -90, 90).

Answer (score 1):

If you run static analysis tool like [Coverity](http://www.coverity.com/products/coverity-save/) it report minor error 
if you combine multiple switch cases like below.

```
   case -90:
   // Intentionally fall through
   case  90:
        w = 480;
        x = '0';
        break;
```

Better to repeat some lines of code than to make some undesired error.

```
       case -90:
            w = 480;
            x = '0';
            break;
       case  90:
            w = 480;
            x = '0';
            break;
```

Answer (score -1):

It can't work. As soon as a break instruction is executed, the remaining code in the switch block is not executed.
You could fix it like this:

```
switch(window.orientation) {
    case   0:
    case 180:
        w = 330;
    case   0:
        x = '-180px';
        break;
    case 180:
        x = '-80px';
        break;
    case -90:
    case  90:
        w = 480;
        x = '0';
        break;
    }
```

Comment: The second `case 0` and `case 180` in the above do absolutely nothing.